# Does Fluentd DaemonSet necessarily needs a ClusterRole or can it be used with a Role as well?

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd

I have a namespace `namespace:development` in my K8s cluster. I wanted to deploy Fluentd following:
[fluentd-daemonset-elasticsearch-rbac.yaml](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/blob/master/fluentd-daemonset-elasticsearch-rbac.yaml)

I **ONLY** changed:

- Type of role from `ClusterRole` to `Role` (the rules parts is the same)
- Name of the `ServiceAccount`
- Instead of `namespace: kube-system` I changed it to `namespace: development` in `ServiceAccount`, `Role` and `RoleBinding`
- `ServiceAccount` in `RoleBinding` to my own service account

When I deployed I got the following error:

```
start_pod_watch: Exception encountered setting up pod watch from Kubernetes API v1 endpoint https://<ip>:443/api: pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:development:my-svc-account" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope ({"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"pods is forbidden: User \\"system:serviceaccount:development:my-svc-account\\" cannot list resource \\"pods\\" in API group \\"\\" at the cluster scope","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"pods"},"code":403} (Fluent::ConfigError)
```

My question: Is this mandatory to have a `clusterRole` to deploy `Fluentd` in a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

If you have change the **Clusterrole** to **role** you also have to update the bindings.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: development

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: fluentd
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: fluentd
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluentd
  namespace: development
---
```

Comment: I see that your `ServiceAccount`,  `Role` and `RoleBinding`is using `namespace: kube-system`. Mine is `namespace:development`

Comment: got that need to update as per need, it will be development only in your case

Comment: But still I see the same arror

Comment: try by removing namespace from resource and use with just pods once, please in role. updated the answer.

Comment: I cannot deploy outside of my namespace. That is my limitation

Comment: try deploying in development namespace only updated the answer check now